# Как определить, жив ли процесс?

Tags: python, windows

Как стандартным питоновским модулем определить, жив ли другой процесс (по `pid`)?

Собственно, есть ли простое и красивое решение вопроса? Как решить задачу нестандартными модулями - знаю. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/check-if-pid-is-not-in-use-in-python) предлагают такой метод:

```
import os

def check_pid(pid):        
    """ Check For the existence of a unix pid. """
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Любопытно, но мне под Винду.

Comment: > Supported by windows now.

Утверждают, что под виндой работает.

Comment: В понедельник обязательно проверю!

Comment: Возражаю. Не работает.
>>> os.kill(20648,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    os.kill(20648,0)
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
>>> os.kill(20648,9)
Киляет чудесно.

Answer (score 1):

Для *nix систем самым простым решением будет:

```
>>> os.path.exists('/proc/<pid>')
```

Для Windows есть пакет WMI, но он нестандартный.

Answer (score 0):

Пока выкручиваюсь так:

```
def __get_running_processes(self):
    """
    Parses cmd> wmic process get ProcessId
    """
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['wmic', 'process', 'get', 'ProcessId'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = proc.stdout.read()
    return map(int,out.split('\r\r\n')[1:-1])
```